# Pass custom parameters to Salesforce Login page

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I'm using Salesforce mobile SDK with Connected App, OAuth2 flow for connecting to Salesforce Community.

Currently, I'm looking for an approach on how to pass additional custom parameters to the Login page and process them by SF Login page.
This should be done just once, during login.

Standard URL, generated by Salesforce SDK is similar to this:

```
https://community.url.force.com/portal/services/oauth2/authorize?
display=touch
&response_type=token
&client_id=CLIENT_ID
&scope=api%20offline_access%20refresh_token%20web
&redirect_uri=mobile://auth/success
&device_id=DEVICE_ID
```

And for example, I need to pass 2 custom additional parameters, listed below:

```
&arg1=val1
&arg2=val2
```

1. Unfortunately, I stuck in my attempts to find the correct approach on how to add these parameters into the Auth URL, without changing SDK functionality.
2. When I'm trying to build and perform this URL manually, I see that Salesforce erase custom parameters before redirection to /login page. So I have no ability to process them by the Salesforce side.